# References are not recognized inside psmatrix

Tags: cross-referencing, pstricks, psmatrix

In a psmatrix environment, labels are not recognized. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[crop=on]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\section{First \label{sec:first}}
\begin{figure}
\caption{this is a figure \label{fig:first}}
\end{figure}

See Figure \ref{fig:first} in Section \ref{sec:first}.
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm,rowsep=0mm]
Did you see Figure \ref{fig:first} in Section \ref{sec:first}?

\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

Prints:

```
 "See Figure 1 in Section 1".
 "Did you see Figure ?? in Section ??"
```

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` compiles the image separately and has no idea of the labels

Comment: AFAIK anything pstricks done this way is written to and external file and compiled on its own. Thus it has no connection to the original file and thus cannot resolve references that refer to the original file.

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` runs the document with `latex`. Getting correct labels two runs of `latex` are needed. After that, the created image has the right label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `runs=2` option to `auto-pst-pdf` -- In this case the external compilation will do the references correctly (It's in the manual ;-))

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[crop=on,runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\section{First \label{sec:first}}
\begin{figure}
\caption{this is a figure \label{fig:first}}
\end{figure}

See Figure \ref{fig:first} in Section \ref{sec:first}.
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0cm,rowsep=0mm]
Did you see Figure \ref{fig:first} in Section \ref{sec:first}?

\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 despite the fact that you clearly cheated by looking in a manual:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: sometimes I cheat, after you scolded other users for them not looking into manuals :-P

Answer (score 4):

If ypu use pdflatex the pstricks fragment is handled as an external file, however if you use

latex, dvips, ps2pdf

then it works in one file and you get

[image]

Comment: Or xelatex directly.